# Stop an R program without error

Tags: r, debugging

Is there any way to stop an R program without error?

For example I have a big source, defining several functions and after it there are some calls to the functions. It happens that I edit some function, and want the function definitions to be updated in R environment, but they are not actually called.

I defined a variable `justUpdate` and when it is `TRUE` want to stop the program just after function definitions.

```
ReadInput <- function(...) ...
Analyze <- function(...) ...
WriteOutput <- function(...) ...

if (justUpdate)
    stop()
# main body
x <- ReadInput()
y <- Analyze(x)
WriteOutput(y)
```

I have called `stop()` function, but the problem is that it prints an error message.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is another option, but I want to stop the source in specific line.

The problem with `q()` or `quit()` is that it terminates R session, but I would like to have the R session still open.

As @JoshuaUlrich proposed `browser()` can be another option, but still not perfect, because the source terminates in a new environment (i.e. the R prompt will change to `Browser[1]>` rather than `>`). Still we can press `Q` to quit it, but I am looking for the straightforward way.

Another option is to use `if (! justUpdate) { main body }` but it's clearing the problem, not solving it.

Is there any better option?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do, and why? This can help us help you.

Comment: @joran I don't want to shut down all error messages

Comment: Either 1) put your function definitions in a separate file (or better yet, a package) from your program and source it after you've updated the function(s); or 2) use `if(!justUpdate) { ... }`. I recommend 1). What you currently want to do is a confusing way to organize your code.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks, maybe this example does not fit the question the best, but is there not anyway to do exactly what stop() function does without error?

Comment: @joran `try(stop(""),silent = TRUE)` does not stop

Comment: Yes to @Joshua's comment above and suggestion 1). Some programming languages call it a *library*, others a *module*, others a *package*, but it is the same idea everywhere: it should only contain functions. The code to be run should only be in your main script. That's programming 101. Anything else you try is just dumb IMHO.

Comment: @Ali yes, it's called `return`, but it doesn't work at the top-level. If you want to stop without error, you'll need to wrap everything in a function.

Comment: If the script is a `knitr` document being rendered, `knitr::knit_exit()` can be used. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33705662/1072349

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the function `browser`.

Comment: Thanks, `browser` is a good choice but not perfect. When I put it in the source code, the program stops successfully from the line I wanted, however the prompt is changed to "Browser[1]>" rather than ">" which means in new environment. I want simply the same environment my source was finished normally

Comment: Just type `Q` at that prompt to close the browser prompt and land back in the main prompt...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Thanks I updated the question, have you any more convenient idea?

Comment: Are you looking for `break`?

Answer (score 30):

I found a rather neat solution [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e5/help/08/11/6953.html). The trick is to turn off all error messages just before calling `stop()`. The function `on.exit()` is used to make sure that error messages are turned on again afterwards. The function looks like this:

```
stop_quietly <- function() {
  opt <- options(show.error.messages = FALSE)
  on.exit(options(opt))
  stop()
}
```

The first line turns off error messages and stores the old setting to the variable `opt`. After this line, any error that occurs will not output a message and therfore, also `stop()` will not cause any message to be printed.

According to the R help,

> `on.exit` records the expression given as its argument as needing to be executed when the current function exits.

The current function is `stop_quietly()` and it exits when `stop()` is called. So the last thing that the program does is call `options(opt)` which will set `show.error.messages` to the value it had, before `stop_quietly()` was called (presumably, but not necessarily, `TRUE`).

Answer (score 17):

There is a nice solution in a mailing list [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg117700.html) that defines a `stopQuietly` function that basically *hides* the error shown from the `stop` function:

```
stopQuietly <- function(...) {
  blankMsg <- sprintf("\r%s\r", paste(rep(" ", getOption("width")-1L), collapse=" "));
  stop(simpleError(blankMsg));
} # stopQuietly()

> stopQuietly()
```

Comment: This solution use awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I have a similar problem and, based on @VangelisTasoulas answer, I got a simple solution.
Inside functions, I have to check if DB is updated. If it is not, stop the execution.

```
r=readline(prompt="Is DB updated?(y/n)")
Is DB updated?(y/n)n
if(r != 'y') stop('\r Update DB')
Update DB
```

Just putting `\r` in the beginning of the message, overwrite `Error:` in the message.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following solution to stop an R program without error:

```
if (justUpdate)
    return(cat(".. Your Message .. "))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This may answer the question, but a short explanation and context can help everyone understand your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had forgotten the answer to this and needed to look it up and landed here... You posted the hint to the answer in your question...

> ctrl+c is another option, but I want to stop the source in specific line.

[Signal an error, warning, or message](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/abort.html)

```html
rlang::inform("Updated Only")
rlang::interrupt()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` something at the line you want to quit the function:

```
f <- function(x, dry=F) { 
   message("hi1")
   if (dry) return(x)
   message("hi2")
   x <- 2*x 
}
y1 <- f(2) # = 4 hi1 hi2
y2 <- f(2, dry=T) # = 2 hi1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer from Stibu on Mar 22 '17 at 7:29, if you want to write a message as a part of stop(), this message is not written.

I perceive strange that following two lines have to be used meaning on.exit(options(options(show....))) doesn't work.

```
opt <- options(show.error.messages = F)
on.exit(options(opt))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it good to write a script and run it with `source()`.  In the script, a write exit statements as a special class of error that a `tryCatch()` can pick up and send back as just a message:

```r
exit <- function(..., .cl = NULL) {
  # Use to capture acceptable stop
  cond <- structure(
    list(.makeMessage(...), .cl),
    class = c("exitError", "error", "condition"),
    names = c("message", "call")
  )

  stop(cond)
}

foo <- function() {
  exit("quit here")
  1
}

tryCatch(
  # rather than foo(), you might use source(filename)
  foo(),
  exitError = function(e) message(e$message)
)
#> quit here
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It would be helpful to add some sample data so that users can see  how those functions work in action.

Comment: @coip, the `foo()` functions as the sample "data" (or in this case a small function to represent a separate script).  It contains an `exit()` call at an arbitrary location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with_options()` in the `withr` package to temporarily disable error messages and then you can call `stop()` directly.

Here is an example:

```
weird_math <- function(x, y, z) {
  
  if (x > z) {
    withr::with_options(
      list(show.error.messages = FALSE),
      {
        print("You can execute other code here if you want")
        stop()
      }
    )
  }
  
  # only runs if x <= z
  x + y ^ z
  
}

weird_math(1, 2, 3)
[1] 9

weird_math(3, 2, 1)
[1] "You can execute other code here if you want"
```

Answer (score -1):

why not just use an if () {} else {}? It's only a couple of characters...

```
f1 <- function(){}
f2 <- function(){}

if (justUpdate) {
} else {
# main body 
}
```

or even

```
f1 <- function(){}
f2 <- function(){}

if (!justUpdate) {
# main body 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code work for me stopped without error messages.

```
opt <- options(show.error.messages = FALSE)
on.exit(options(opt))
break
```

Comment: break is for exiting for and while loops. Rest of the answer is before before by others.