# Stopping an R script quietly and return control to the terminal

Tags: r

I often run my scripts from an R terminal with `source('my_script.r')`. I would like be able to use a statement in my scripts that quietly terminate execution of the script anywhere I type it and that returns control to the terminal, where I can inspect my variables.

The answers to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512175/how-to-stop-a-r-script) suggest using

```
q()
```

or

```
stop()
```

to stop an R script, but `q()`exits the session, and `stop()` throws an exception and is not quiet (especially if I have something like `options(error=traceback)`  activated, since it forces R to print the call stack).

Is there a way to quietly stop execution of the script and return control to the R terminal with a short command?

Comment: Have you tried `browser()`?

Comment: [We've been here before.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14469522/271616)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich -- Funny. I hadn't seen that one, but was also just about to edit to mention typing `Q` to exit the browser!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: it was the first result when I searched for "[r] stop source".

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaUlrich I didn't see that question either. I think both questions are very similar. I would like to directly return to the original environment, but from I read in the comments, I need to type `Q` to do that (and I imagine I lose my variables doing so), is that the case?

Comment: You do realize that the desire to both return to the original, calling environment and also retain access to all variables from inside your scripts/functions is basically contrary to how R works at a fundamental design level, re:scoping?