# How to request an early exit when knitting an Rmd document?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Let's say you have an R markdown document that will not render cleanly.

I know you can set the `knitr` chunk option `error` to `TRUE` to request that evaluation continue, even in the presence of errors. You can do this for an individual chunk via `error = TRUE` or in a more global way via `knitr::opts_chunk$set(error = TRUE)`.

But sometimes there are errors that are still fatal to the knitting process. Two examples I've recently encountered: trying to `unlink()` the current working directory (oops!) and calling `rstudioapi::getVersion()` from inline R code when RStudio is not available. Is there a general description of these sorts of errors, i.e. the ones beyond the reach of `error = TRUE`? Is there a way to tolerate errors in inline R code vs in chunks?

Also, are there more official ways to halt knitting early or to automate debugging in this situation?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To exit early from the knitting process, you may use the function `knitr::knit_exit()` anywhere in the source document (in a code chunk or inline expression). Once `knit_exit()` is called, **knitr** will ignore all the rest of the document and write out the results it has collected so far.

There is no way to tolerate errors in inline R code at the moment. You need to make sure inline R code always runs without errors<sup>1</sup>. If errors do occur, you should see the range of lines that produced the error from the **knitr** log in the console, of the form `Quitting from lines x1-x2 (filename.Rmd)`. Then you can go to the file `filename.Rmd` and see what is wrong with the lines from `x1` to `x2`. Same thing applies to code chunks with the chunk option `error = FALSE`.

Beyond the types of errors mentioned above, it may be tricky to find the source of the problem. For example, when you unintentionally `unlink()` the current directory, it should not stop the knitting process, because `unlink()` succeeded anyway. You may run into problems after the knitting process, e.g., LaTeX/HTML cannot find the output figure files. In this case, you can try to apply `knit_exit()` to all code chunks in the document one by one. One way to achieve this is to set up a chunk hook to run `knit_exit()` after a certain chunk. Below is an example of using linear search (you can improve it by using bisection instead):

```
#' Render an input document chunk by chunk until an error occurs
#' 
#' @param input the input filename (an Rmd file in this example)
#' @param compile a function to compile the input file, e.g. knitr::knit, or
#'   rmarkdown::render
knit_debug = function(input, compile = knitr::knit) {
  library(knitr)
  lines = readLines(input)
  chunk = grep(all_patterns$md$chunk.begin, lines)  # line number of chunk headers

  knit_hooks$set(debug = function(before) {
    if (!before) {
      chunk_current <<- chunk_current + 1
      if (chunk_current >= chunk_num) knit_exit()
    }
  })

  opts_chunk$set(debug = TRUE)

  # try to exit after the i-th chunk and see which chunk introduced the error
  for (chunk_num in seq_along(chunk)) {
    chunk_current = 0  # a chunk counter, incremented after each chunk
    res = try(compile(input))
    if (inherits(res, 'try-error')) {
      message('The first error came from line ', chunk[chunk_num])
      break
    }
  }
}
```

---

1. This is by design. I think it is a good idea to have `error = TRUE` for code chunks, since sometimes we want to show errors, for example, for teaching purposes. However, if I allow errors for inline code as well, authors may fail to recognize fatal errors in the inline code. Inline code is normally used to embed *values* inline, and I don't think it makes much sense if an inline value is an error. Imagine a sentence in a report like `The P-value of my test is ERROR`, and if **knitr** didn't signal the error, it will require the authors to read the report output very carefully to spot this issue. I think it is a bad idea to have to rely on human eyes to find such mistakes.

Answer (score 14):

IMHO, difficulty debugging an Rmd document is a warning that something is wrong. I have a rule of thumb: Do the heavy lifting *outside* the Rmd. Do rendering inside the Rmd, and *only* rendering. That keeps the Rmd code simple.

My large R programs look like this.

```
data <- loadData()
analytics <- doAnalytics(data)
rmarkdown::render("theDoc.Rmd", envir=analytics)
```

(Here, *doAnalytics* returns a list or environment. That list or environment gets passed to the Rmd document via the *envir* parameter, making the results of the analytics computations available inside the document.)

The *doAnalytics* function does the complicated calculations. I can debug it using the regular tools, and I can easily check its output. By the time I call *rmarkdown::render*, I know the hard stuff is working correctly. The Rmd code is just "print this" and "format that", easy to debug.

This division of responsibility has served me well, and I can recommend it. Especially compared to the mind-bending task of debugging complicated calculations buried inside a dynamically rendered document.

Comment: Good suggestions! The document I was debugging required the use of `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = ...)`, which I normally avoid like the plague and explains how I inadvertently attempted to delete working directory. Sometimes the debugging really must happen in the R markdown domain.

Comment: @pteetor - this is interesting and I've never thought about this. can you provide an example .R and .Rmd file showing how this works for a real example (iris, mtcars, flights, whatever)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Stephen! I created a gist to illustrate the idea: https://gist.github.com/pteetor/c79b4525c49de40c8b5b

Comment: The other side of this is that if everything is in the .Rmd, you have a single document that shows how your (e.g.) scientific paper was generated, which is nice for reproducible research. Perhaps a solution is to put your analytics into functions within the Rmd, so they can be run and debugged at the command line.