# how can I terminate a call chain in r without using stop() or quit()?

Tags: r

Assume that in R there is a sequence of functions calling one another:

```
a = function() {...b()...}
b = function() {...c()...}
c = function() {...d()...}
```

and so on, where ... indicates omitted code. Now let's say that function d reaches a satisfactory state and wants to terminate the entire call chain and return to the Global Environment (assuming this is being run from within R GUI). Is there a way for function d to terminate the entire call chain? I realize stop() can achieve this, but stop() generates an error, which is not what I want. I also do not want to use quit() as I do not want to terminate the R GUI session.

ADDENDUM:
I also do not want to have to process a chain of return statements. This is because it is not necessarily the case that the calling functions will have knowledge of the called functions, which can be plugged in and unplugged, so to speak.

Comment: You want `d()` to `return` something that allows `c()` and thence `b()` and `a()` to also terminate given some feature or attribute or class of the object returned up the chain. See `?return`

Comment: I'm familiar with return(), but for a good design reason I'd prefer not to have to process a chain of return() statements.

Comment: I'm at a loss then; there's not much else you can do beyond throwing an error or returning! Sounds like you just want `d` to return; `c()` called `d()` so it needs to know how to handle the object returned by `d()` or perhaps it doesn't, it can just `return()` (or implicitly return by having `d()` as the last statement) once `d()` is done. None of the functions need process or check objects returned from lower down the stack. However, if you are trying to get something out of them, you should be returning something; otherwise it's not a functional style in the typical sense of R.

Comment: check the `stopQuietly` function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469522/stop-an-r-program-without-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: In my setup stopQuietly generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really elegant but you could use a "break" variable that's living out of the the functions environments using `<<-`. Maybe something like that:

```
do_break <- FALSE

a = function(break = do_break) {
        ...
        if(condition) {
            do_break <<- TRUE
        }
        if(!do_break) {
            b(do_break)
        }
        ...
    }

b = function(break = do_break) {
        ...
        if(condition) {
            do_break <<- TRUE
        }
        if(!do_break) {
            c(do_break)
        }
        ...
    }

c = function(break = do_break) {
        ...
        if(condition) {
            do_break <<- TRUE
        }
        if(!do_break) {
            d(do_break)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think this answers the question. Let's say that function d() wants to terminate the call chain; how does do_break let it do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work but the idea would be that if `do_break` is `TRUE`, calling `c(do_break)` would just not call `d()`. Same for the next functions (`d()`, ...). This way you can first declare `do_break` to be `FALSE`, call `a(do_break)` which will in turn call the cascade of functions. Once any of the function pings the condition in the `if()` statement, `do_break` will update to `FALSE` and the next functions will not be called. Hard to tell if it works without more details on the functions though.