# Terminate the exectuion with STOP() but not throwing an "Error" message in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I want a function that would terminate the program when there is no data are returned and print out a message to users about there is no new data are found.
However, I don't want my function throws users an "error" message. For example,

```
my_update_function <- function () {
  df <- data  # get data 
  if (nrow(df) == 0) {
   stop('\r no new data found')
   }
   else {
   # do some updates
   }
}
```

current output:
**Error in my_update_function() : 
no new data found**

my expected output: **no new data found**

How can I get rid of the "Error" in my output message but the program is terminated when the condition is true.

Comment: This is close to a question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469522/stop-an-r-program-without-error), one answer of which defines a custom `stopQuietly` function that might be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would hide the word "error" on the console but the program still sees it as an error. Referencing on [Stop an R program without error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469522/stop-an-r-program-without-error/42945293#42945293)

```
if (nrow(new_data) == 0) {
    message(log_date, " - ","no new_data is found ")
    opt <- options(show.error.messages=FALSE)
    on.exit(options(opt))
    stop()

}
else { # DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is just a repost [of Stibu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42945293/903061), so I think (a) you should attribute it to them, and (b) we can close the question as a dupe of the one where the answer was found.