# Calling stop( ) within function causes R CMD Check to throw error

Tags: r, namespaces, exit

I am attempting to call stop( ) from within an internal package function (stop_quietly()) which should break the function and return to the topline. This works except that R CMD Check thinks this is an error because I am forcing stop.

How do I get around the R CMD check interpreting this as an error? The function needs to stop since it requires user input as a confirmation before it creates a file directory tree at a given location. The code currently produces a message and stops the function.

```
tryCatch({
      path=normalizePath(path=where, winslash = "\\", mustWork = TRUE)
      message(paste0("This will create research directories in the following directory: \n",path))
      confirm=readline(prompt="Please confirm [y/n]:")
      if(tolower(stringr::str_trim(confirm)) %in% c("y","yes","yes.","yes!","yes?")){
         .....
         dir.create(path, ... [directories])
         .....
       }
       message("There, I did some work, now you do some work.")
      }
        else{
        message("Okay, fine then. Don't do your research. See if I care.")
        stop_quietly()
      }
    },error=function(e){message("This path does not work, please enter an appropriate path \n or set the working directory with setwd() and null the where parameter.")})
```

stop_quietly is an exit function [I took from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469522/stop-an-r-program-without-error) with the modification of error=NULL which suppresses R executing the error handler as a Browser. I do not want the function to terminate to a Browser I just want it to quit without throwing an error in the R CMD Check.

```
stop_quietly <- function() {
  opt <- options(show.error.messages = FALSE, error=NULL)
  on.exit(options(opt))
  stop()
}
```

Here is the component of the error R CMD produces:

```
-- R CMD check results ------------------------------------------------ ResearchDirectoR 1.0.0 ----
Duration: 12.6s

> checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in 'ResearchDirectoR-Ex.R' failed
  The error most likely occurred in:
  
  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: create_directories
  > ### Title: Creates research directories
  > ### Aliases: create_directories
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  > create_directories()
  This will create research directories in your current working directory: 
  C:/Users/Karnner/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUfqXvY/ResearchDirectoR.Rcheck
  Please confirm [y/n]:
  Okay, fine then. Don't do your research. See if I care.
  Execution halted
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what’s the exact error message that `R CMD check` produces? (It’s probably not relevant for the question but it sounds bizarre.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  I'd guess the call to `stop()` happened in an example.  Examples aren't allowed to generate errors unless you wrap them in `tryCatch()` or equivalent.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It was thrown by an example, so I am left with how to wrap this in a tryCatch() without calling it an error...because it is not an error, per se.  Error added to original post.

Comment: @JonathanFluharty-Jaidee Ha, ok, got it. Obviously `R CMD check` *itself* relies on installed error handlers, so if you disable that, it will fail. You need to ensure that `R CMD check` doesn’t end up executing that particular code (e.g. via examples, as in your case, or in a vignette). To fix this, just wrap your example code in `\donotrun{…}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function has global side effects, I think `check` isn't going to like it.  It would be different if you required the user to put `tryCatch` at the top level, and then let it catch the error.  But think about this scenario:  a user defines `f()` and calls it:

```
f <- function() {
  call_your_function()
  do_something_essential()
}
f()
```

If your function silently caused it to skip the second line of `f()`, it could cause a lot of trouble for the user.

What you could do is tell the user to wrap the call to your function in `tryCatch()`, and have it catch the error:

```
f <- function() {
  tryCatch(call_your_function(), error = function(e) ...)
  do_something_essential()
}
f()
```

This way the user will know that your function failed, and can decide whether or not to continue.

From discussion in the comments and your edit to the question, it seems like your function is only intended to be used interactively, so the above scenario isn't an issue.  In that case, you can avoid the `R CMD check` problems by skipping the example unless it is being run interactively.  This is fairly easy:  in the help page for a function like `create_directories()`, set up your example as

```
if (interactive()) {
  create_directories()
  # other stuff if you want
}
```

The checks are run with `interactive()` returning `FALSE`, so this will stop the error from ever happening in the check.  You could also use `tryCatch` within `create_directories()` to catch the error coming up from below if that makes more sense in your package.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but the stop_silently( ) is internal to the package so users should not be accessing it. The main function generates a directory tree of common folders I use for research and creates pre-templated .Rnw files to speed up research project startup. The stop_silently() is a failsafe, the program asks the user to confirm where to place the directory tree. They confirm with [y/n], a "n" input should generate a message i.e. ("O.K., I won't do that.") and then  terminate the function. There are other error handlers wrapping that I need skipped. Updated main post.

Comment: Your example calls `create_directories()`, and it bombs.  If it was called by `call_your_function()` in my example, `do_something_essential()` would never be called, and the user would not receive an error message (because you silenced it).  If you want it to be entirely internal, then put your own code in `tryCatch()`.  If `create_directories()` is only intended to be called interactively, then put the example in `if (interactive()) ...` and it won't be called in `R CMD check`.

Comment: I think I understand your concern is a user using my function in their own code would also terminate any functions they create. That is indeed an issue. I think I will go the interactive route. Can you update your original answer so I can grant points?

Comment: I've changed the last part.